# Proof regarding prime numbers:

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

**THEOREM:**

If a prime $p$ divides a product $a_1 \cdot \cdot \cdot a_n$, then $p$ divides at least one of its factors, $a_i$.

This is my attempt at the proof, the book I am reading from suggests using induction on the number of factors, but I went a different direction because I couldn't get anywhere with induction:

Suppose $p\mid a_1\cdot\cdot\cdot a_n$ and $ p\nmid a_i^*$ where $a_i^* = \dfrac{a_1\cdot\cdot\cdot a_n}{a_i}$ and $a_i$ is one of the factors of the product.

We know that, 
\begin{align*}
\gcd(p,a_i^*) = 1\\
a_i = \gcd(a_ip,a_ia_i^*)
\end{align*}

And since $p\mid a_ip,a_1\cdot\cdot\cdot a_n \Longrightarrow p\mid(a_ip,a_1\cdot\cdot\cdot a_n) \Longrightarrow p\mid a_i$.

Has the theorem been proven?

Comment: There is a bit of trouble with the part $p\nmid a_i^*$. Are you sure such an $i$ always exists? What happens if it doesn't?

Comment: What's your definition of "prime"? In number theory it is often defined as an element such that $p\mid ab$ implies $p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$ (possibly both). Thus, if you suppose that $p\mid a_1\cdots a_{n-1}$ always implies $p\mid a_i$ for some $1\le i<n$, and we know that $p\mid a_1\cdots a_n$ implies $p\mid a_1\cdots a_{n-1}$ or $p\mid a_n$...

Comment: @EuYu if such an $i$ doesn't exist then the theorem is proven because that implies there exists at at least one of the factors of the product that is divisible by $p$.

Comment: @kvmu Are you counting $a_i^*$ as the factor? The question seems to be asking to prove that $p$  divides one of the $a_i$s. How exactly would you fill in your details?

Comment: @EuYu $a_i^*$ is the product $a_1\cdot\cdot\cdot a_n$ except without a factor of $a_i$

Comment: @kvmu Yes, I know. $p\mid a_i^*$ implies that $p$ divides the product of the $a_i$s and not any particular $a_i$. You are essentially taking the statement for granted in the proof.

Comment: @EuYu Heh, apologies for being difficult. In any case, I don't see how I am taking the statement as granted - I'll explain how I see it, and you point out the mistake. So, suppose that $p$ divides the product. Now, say the product is divided by $a_n$ and say that the new product is not divisible by $p$ then from what I've done that implies that $a_n$ is divisible by $p$. Otherwise, you can keep checking until you reach an $i$ where it is true.

Comment: @kvmu I agree that _if_ there exists some $i$ such that $p\nmid a_i^*$ then your proof is perfectly valid. But for any integer which is not square-free in $p$ that won't happen. For example, take $p=2$ and $12$ with the factorization $a_1 = a_2 = 2$ and $a_3 = 3$. Then $a_1^* = a_2^* = 6$ and $a_3^* = 4$ so $p=2$ divides every $a_i^*$. Can you elaborate in detail how you address this?

Comment: @EuYu Ahh, now I see where you are coming from. Now I have to prove even if $p\mid a_i^*$, there exists at least one $i$ such that $p\mid a_i$, which has got me against a brick wall.

Comment: As that is no proof because there's a contradiction (you have to consider the impossibly defined case $p\mid a_i^*$ EuYu noticed), you should answer your own question saying that exactly, perhaps including another non-inductive solution.

Answer (score 1):

I got confused by your argument.  The induction follows easily from the following result.

*Claim:* If $p$ divides $ab$ then $p$ divides $a$ or $p$ divides $b$ (or both).

Because $p$ is prime, its only divisors are $1$ and $p$.  This means $\gcd(a,p)$ must be either $p$ or $1$.  If $\gcd(a,p) = p$, then $p$ divides $a$ and we're done.

Otherwise $\gcd(a,p) = 1$.  Then using Euclid's algorithm you get

$$ra + sp = 1$$

for integers $r$ and $s$.  Multiplying both sides by $b$ you get

$$rab + spb = b$$

The left hand side is divisible by $p$ because $p$ divides $ab$.  This shows that $b$ is divisible by $p$.

Now you can use this to prove the result for an arbritary product $a_1 \cdots a_n$, by using induction on the number of factors.  What if the theorem were true for all products with $n-1$ factors?  Hint: integer multiplication is associative.

Comment: I think I've done exactly the same thing that you have with Euclid's example just with an arbitrary product. I would really like to do this with induction, though. I would appreciate another hint :-)